# count rows in result width fulltext search mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to ask if anybody can help me with this query

```
SELECT count(MATCH(product_text) AGAINST('lorem*' in boolean mode)) AS score FROM table_products WHERE MATCH (text) AGAINST ('lorem*' in boolean mode) limit 0,50000
```

There is fulltext index on column text. A.m. query return sum of rows as score. 
What I wont is to count fulltext search results. If the number of results(rows)
is higher than 50000, than count-sum 50000 will be returned, otherwise the exact count of
of results is returned.

Problem is that it is not fast on table width 1,5 million rows if user try to find for example  word "lorem" and this word appears in table f.e. more than 500 000 x.

I tried also

```
SELECT id,name,product_text,price, MATCH(product_text) AGAINST('lorem*' in boolean mode) AS score FROM table_products WHERE MATCH(product_text) AGAINST('lorem*' in boolean mode) and show_product='1' limit 0,50000
```

... width php mysql_num_rows

Another problem is that in following query mysql use fulltext index only
and sort by another column or by score is than slow

```
SELECT id,name,product_text,price, MATCH(product_text) AGAINST('lorem*' in boolean mode) AS score FROM table_products WHERE MATCH(product_text) AGAINST('lorem*' in boolean mode) and show_product='1' order by score desc limit 0,50000
```

resp. (..order by name, order by price)

Is there another better and faster way?

Many thanks for any help.